# Do all guilds get all guild perks automatically?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When I used to play the game it used to be that you had to level up to get perks and stuff. But now I'm not sure.

I was thinking of making my own guild so I can use the guild bank for my alts, but will I get guild perks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/patch-notes/6-0-2

> Guilds no longer have levels. All guilds have access to a standard set of bonuses and abilities on creation.

---

Guild achievements and guild reputation are still around with the rewards associated with those progressions.